# Sqlalchemy many to many relationship with conditional join

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I would like to build an SQL relationship model in sqlalchemy and fastapi which will always only retrieve the items from a given relationship if the boolean in their deleted column is set to false (in other words not deleted). I am trying to use primaryjoin as shown below

This is a simplified version of apples model:

```
class Apples(Base, Audited):

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, server_default=observation_id_seq.next_value())
    date = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=text('NOW()'), index=True)
    plumes = relationship('Plume', secondary=plumes_observations_table, primaryjoin='and_(plumes_observations.c.observation_id==Observation.id, Plume.deleted==False)', back_populates='observations', lazy='selectin', cascade='all,delete',
                      passive_updates=False)
```

The pears_apples_table is defined as follows:

```
pears_apples_table = Table('pears_apples', Base.metadata,
                              Column('pear_id', ForeignKey('pear.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True),
                              Column('apple_id', ForeignKey('apple.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True, index=True)
                              )
```

The Pear table is defined as follows:

```
    class Pear(Base, Audited):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), index=True, default=datetime.datetime.now(), nullable=False)
    Apples = relationship('Apple', secondary=pears_apples_table, back_populates='pears', lazy='selectin', viewonly=True)
```

With the above code I get an error at run time:

```
missing FROM-clause entry for table "pear" LINE 18: ...pples_1.apple_id = apple.id AND pear.dele...
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction here and explain what could be wrong with the current configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to this problem. I needed to use both primaryjoin and secondary join. I implemented the joins like this in the apple's relationship with pear:

```
             primaryjoin="(Apple.id==pears_apples.c.apple_id)",
             secondaryjoin="and_(Pear.id==pears_apples.c.pear_id, Pear.deleted==False)")
```